# Criar outra classe ou não? PHP/POO

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Eu tenho duas tabelas e classes de finança, sendo uma para `Despesas` e outra para `Receitas`. As duas tem algumas colunas iguais e outras diferentes.
Preciso usar um método (Que já criei) que une as duas tabelas e faz uma listagem com base em um filtro.
O mais correto seria criar uma nova classe `ReceitaDespesa` ou adicionar o método em uma das duas classes já existentes?
Caso seja mais viável criar uma nova classe, deveria também declarar as variáveis para cada atributo de cada tabela?

Receita: https://pastebin.com/5DgxrhnD
Despesa: https://pastebin.com/LbfeCR2N
ReceitaDespesa: https://pastebin.com/inWC65bq

Comment: Precisará ser mais específico. Que método é esse? Quem são as classes? Que filtro é esse? Qual o resultado esperado?

Comment: É um método que lista as receitas e despesas.. o filtro é pra saber se alguns dados foram informados no formulário pra incrementar a query do sql.

Comment: Se *despesas* e *receitas* possuem métodos em comum, você pode criar uma `class operacoes` e fazer que ela seja herdada. (DRY) você evita repetir os mesmos blocos de código, além de mais ágil é mais fácil manter.

Comment: Tem como herdar das duas classes?

Comment: Ainda muito confuso. Tem como [edit] a pergunta e adicionar os códigos?

Comment: Editei a pergunta adicionando 3 links.. Dá uma olhada nos links e lê a pergunta outra vez que creio que agora com os links dê pra entender melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Opa Eduardo, porque não cria uma abstração de dados ou seja uma classe abstrata e usa uma herança nas duas classes assim todos os métodos comuns ficam na classe abstrata com acesso por herança e os métodos pertencentes só a  finanças e despesas dentro de sua classe modelo.

```
abstract class Financas{ 
    public function __construct(){}

    protected function Get(){}

    protected  function Set(){}

    //Gets e Sets e métodos compartilhados entre Despesas e Receitas

}

class Despesas extends Financas{

   public function __construct(){} 

}


class Receitas extends Financas{

   public function __construct(){} 

}
```

Só um esboço mal feito para entender o funcionamento ....

Aqui tem tb um exemplo legal sobre isso [PHP abstração de dados](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.abstract.php)

Abração

Seguindo a solicitação em comentário para auxílio estou alterando essa resposta:

Eduardo tá tudo praticamente montado basta ir na classe Receita e aonde está **"class Receita {"**  colocar assim **class Receita  extends ReceitaDespesas{"** eu mudaria o nome dessa classe para Financas ou outra nomeclatura qualquer. Fica melhor a coesão. e na classe Despesas aonde está **"class Despesa {"** coloque  **"class Despesa extends ReceitaDespesas {"** pronto as instâncias da classe Receita e despesas irão acessar os métodos da classe herdada ReceitaDespesas

Montagem:

```
abstract class ReceitasDesesas{
    /* aqui deve colocar todos os métodos compartilhados entre as duas 
    classes abaixo, essa é uma típica classe abstrata poderia definir 
    abstract antes do class.*/  
}

class Receita extends ReceitaDespesas{
    // aqui fica como está
}

class Despesas extends ReceitaDespesas{
    // aqui fica como está
}
```

Agora deve me perguntar, como acessar os métodos dentro de Receita e Despesas direto da classe herdada? Resposta: da mesma forma que acessa um método interno de dentro da própia classe que a definiu com o operador

> $this
>   ;

```
abstract class ReceitasDesesas{
   protected $observacoes ;       

   /*Crie métodos dentro desta classe para colunas 
   do banco que tenham colunas iguais  em Despesas e Receitas exemplo set e 
   get entre outros métodos de formatação como por exemplo o método 
   observações copiado da sua classe*/

   /*Isso vai evitar métodos duplicados facilita e agiliza a manutenção do 
   sistema*/

   protected function setObservacoes($observacoes) {
      $this->observacoes = $observacoes;
   }


   abstract function setIdUsuario() { }


   protected function getObversacoes() {
      return $this->observacoes;
   }

}

class Receitas extends ReceitaDespesas{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->setObservacoes("Receita vinda da lavaJato caixa dois ...."); 
    }

   // Aqui criar métodos pertencentes apenas a receitas. 
}

class Despesas extends ReceitaDespesas{
   public function __construct(){
       $this->setObservacoes("Despesas com propina de deputado ....");
   }

   //Aqui criar métodos pertencentes apenas a despesas.
}
```

Repare o seguinte eu adicionei lá em cima o abstract antes do class isso é para indicar que essa classe é uma abstração de dados ou seja tudo que é igual variáveis e métodos  em Receitas e Despesas vai ser posto ali e como herdei nas classes modelos passa a pertencer a classe que a herda. E portanto, como se trata de uma abstração de dados, a classe não pode ser instanciada apenas herdada se eu tirar o abstract ai sim poderia ser instanciada a parte.

Repare também que eu usei protected antes de definir a variável $observações e nos métodos set() e get() isso indica que esses métodos e variáveis só vão poder ser acessados para herdeiros dessa classe.

Você pode utilizar : protected , public e private

> public: acesso ao método ou variável de dentro da própia classe ou a qualquer interface que instancia a mesma.
>
> protected: acesso ao método ou variável apenas para a classe que é herdeira.
>
> private: acesso ao método ou variável apenas internamente dentro da classe que a definiu.

Um outro aspecto interessante que posso descrever é o uso de métodos abstratos
repare que coloquei um exemplo na nossa classe abstrata

> abstract function setIdUsuario();

e não defini o conteúdo do método. Isso serve para especificar que ambas as classes que herdarem DespesasReceitas tem que obrigatoriamente implementar internamente a classe setIdUsuario(); isso ajuda quando você precisa ter esse método sendo implementado de formas diferentes em várias classes que herdam a abstração. Ou seja em despesas poderia utilizar o CPF do cliente e em receitas o identidade do cliente, por exemplo.

PS: no caso do exemplo acima se executar vai dar erro dizendo que um método foi definido como abstrato:

> abstract setIdUsuario()

mas não foi implementado nas classe Receitas e Despesas obrigando você a implementa-los.

Por fim encerro pedindo desculpas, eu não tinha nenhum exemplo funcional melhor para inserir. Então escrevi tudo o que tenho em mente.

Se houver mais dúvidas não hesite em me chamar

Abração

Comment: Cada classe num arquivo diferente ou tudo no mesmo arquivo?

Comment: Faça cada classe em um arquivo diferente irmão para manter a coesão e facilitar na hora da manutenção. E use um diretório para modularizar o projeto dentro dele coloque as interfaces do módulo, classe modelo do modulo onde tenho Set e Gets e Métodos que utilizo nas interfaces e arquivos de constantes do módulo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo... Ainda estou um pouco confuso quanto a isto, mas vou ver alguns vídeos sobre abstração e herança... Tentei alterar aqui no meu código mas não deu muito certo.

Comment: pode alterar sua pergunta e postar o código eu oriento como montar se desejar...

Comment: Os códigos estão nos 3 links da pergunta. Se me ajudar agradeço de coração!!!